# I want to download the content of a DriveItem , how do I get the driveItem's Id?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sdk, onedrive

I am trying to get a DriveItem by the Item Id, however when I attempt this, I get an error saying the no item matching the Id I gave was found. I am using the MSGraph .NET SDK.

```
var items = await  GraphClient.Me.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().GetAsync();
var files = items.CurrentPage;
foreach (var file in files)
{
     if (file.File.MimeType == "application/json" && filename == file.Name)
     {
        var itemId = file.Id;                   
        return await GraphClient.Me.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children[itemId].Request().GetAsync();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `children` collection expects a file name as the key. Since you have the item id (from `file.Id`) you want to use it with the `items` collection:

```cs
...
return await GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId].Request().GetAsync();
...
```